# Factory girl has one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Trying to build has_one association with factory girl with no success.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy, required: true
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@email.com'
    password '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'
    trait :with_profile do
      profile
    end
  end

  create :profile do
    first_name 'First'
    last_name 'Last'
    type 'Consumer'
  end
end

build :user, :with_profile
-> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank
```

If I'm adding user association to profile factory, then additional user is created and saved to DB. So I have 2 users (persisted and new) and 1 profile for persisted user.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

A quick workaround that works for me is to wrap the profile creation in an after(:create) block, like this :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@email.com'
    password '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'
    trait :with_profile do
      after(:create) do |u|
        u.profile = create(:profile, user: u)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :profile do
    first_name 'First'
    last_name 'Last'
    type 'Consumer'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Building the associations in after_create worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@email.com'
    password '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'
    trait :with_profile do
      profile { Profile.create! }
    end
  end

  factory :profile do
    first_name 'First'
    last_name 'Last'
    type 'Consumer'
    user
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still receiving `Validation failed: User can't be blank`

Answer (score 0):

This is a great way to build your profile and user factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email 'user@email.com'
    password '123456'
    password_confirmation '123456'

    factory :user_with_profile do
      after(:create) do |user|
        create(:profile, user: user)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When we create a new user with: `user = build_stubbed(:user_with_profile)`, the user profile will be created as well, as well.

This article is a worthwhile read if you want to research more about [factory girl associations](https://kolosek.com/factory-girl-associations).